# How to have PHPUnit do something if an assertion fails

Tags: php, sql, phpunit

I'm testing that a function properly adds data to a db, but I want the test data removed after the test is finished.  If the test fails, it quits at the failure and never gets the chance to delete the test rows.

It's the only test that hits the db, so I don't really want to do anything in the tearDown() method.

I'm testing an $obj->save() type method that saves data parsed from a flat file.

Comment: Instead of bending PHPUnit, maybe your test would work on a CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE? (Assuming you're not developing the database.)

Comment: Then I would have to bend the actual php code, I'm testing an $obj->save() type method.  I ended up calling save(), querying the db and storing the results in a variable, removing the test data, then finally making the assertions.  I feel like phpunit has something that lets you run a bit of code on test case failure though, I just can't find it in the docs for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use separate databases for development/production and testing. Which are identical in structure but every time you perform testing you drop the testing db and restore it from some data fixtures. The point is that this way you can be absolutely sure that your db contains the same set of data every time you run your tests. So deleting test data is no big deal.

Comment: I agree this is how it should be done, I can't imagine convincing my office to start doing this though.

Answer (score 3):

If your database supports transactions, you could issue a start_transaction at the beginning of the test.  If the test fails (causing the program to quit), an implicit rollback will be executed and undo your changes.  If the test succeeds, issue an explicit rollback.

Another option is to wrap the assertions in a try-catch statement - this prevents the test from halting (as well as other automatic features like capturing screenshots), and you can do whatever you need from that point.

Comment: this actually answers the OP, unlike the other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the suggested approach for database testing via the [Database Testcase Extension](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html)?

Basically, if the test *fails* (read if there is not an error that makes PHPUnit exit), there should be no issues because the database is seeded on startup of the testcase:

> the default implementation in PHPUnit will automatically truncate all tables specified and then insert the data from your data set in the order specified by the data set.

so there should be no need to do that manually. Even if there is an error, PHPUnit will clear the table on next run.